# Out of bounds error, while reading file then splitting it

Tags: java

I've been getting an Array Index Out of Bounds Error.

Basically I have a file where a user name and password is saved lke this: user:password
I'm trying to read the file to check if a new user is already signed in or not. This is in a thread and also using a socket.

```
private void authentication(String user, String password) {
        List<String> nomes = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> pass = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("users.txt", true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("users.txt"));
            //String line;
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
                String[] pair = line.split(";");
                nomes.add(pair[0]);
                pass.add(pair[1]);
            }
            /*while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] info = line.split(":");
                System.out.println(line);
                System.out.println(info[0]);
                System.out.println(info[1]);
            }*/
            
            if(nomes.isEmpty()) {
                out.println(user + ":" + password);
                System.out.println("Novo Utilizador Autenticado.");
                System.out.println("Bem Vindo!!");
            }else if(nomes.contains(user)) {
                bw.newLine();
                if(password.equals(pass.get(nomes.indexOf(user)))) {
                    System.out.println("Utilizador autenticado com sucesso!");
                    System.out.println("Bem Vindo de Volta!!");
                }
            }else {
                terminate();
            }
            bw.close();
            br.close();
            out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              System.out.println("An error occurred.");
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
    }
```

The error is happening in the last line on the pair[1]. It has a value but for some reason isn't seeing it.

Comment: If you use `line.split(";")` on a line that does not have a ";", then you will get an out of bounds error when you try to access `pair[1]` because it does not exist. To solve this you should check if the line contains a ";" and if it does not then just skip it, or add a blank password to the pass array.

Comment: the real issue would seem to be a typo, using semicolon ";" instead of colon ":" in the split line.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. But the comment part below has the ":" instead of the typo and it had the same error. Now I don't know why but it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text in the file is like "user:password" and you are trying to split it with ";". So pair[1] won't have any value. You should try split it with ":"

Comment: ok, good catch. but see the commentated part below. There it is the ":" and i swear it gave the same error, now for whatever reason it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the **values dynamically** using index instead of hardcoded 0,1 to avoid index out of bond exception :

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] info = line.split(":");
    int index = 0;
    System.out.println(line);
    while(index < info.length){
        System.out.println(info[index++]);
    }
}
```